# Is there a way to set title value to the containers in ipywidgets?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

All,
    I am trying to build a small UI as a wrapper for a tool I have. I am trying to use ipywidgets in Jupyter notebooks to do this and I am running into a small issue. It is not sufficiently clear by looking at the Read The Docs page as to how it can be addressed, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I am looking at, this is straight from the documentation:

````
```
import ipywidgets as widgets 

tab_contents = ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']
children = [widgets.Text(description=name) for name in tab_contents]
tab = widgets.Tab()
tab.children = children
tab.titles = [str(i) for i in range(len(children))]
tab
```
````

This looks great, except that the tabs do not have a title. The documentation basically says, titles can be set the same way as Accordion container, but even that container doesn't show how to set a title. Would appreciate any help in this matter.

Best 
Uday

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1307):

```
from ipywidgets import *
names = ['General', 'Representation', 'Preference', 'Theme', 'Extra', 'Help']
tab = Tab([IntSlider(description='hi') for _ in names])
[tab.set_title(i, title) for i, title in enumerate(names)]
tab
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep it's not the most obvious way to do it. Here is an alternative that avoids a list comprehension.

```py
for title, (index, _) in zip(tab_contents, enumerate(tab.children)):
    tab.set_title(index, title)
```

Comment: yeah, thanks for sharing this alternative. it took some digging until i found that on Gitub. This is a helpful tip to have in my back pocket.